# Swift delete parts from JSON to decode it

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have this as response from API

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
      "sector": "Technology"
    }
  },
  "FB": {
    "quote": {
      "symbol": "FB",
      "companyName": "Facebook Inc.",
      "sector": "Technology"
    }
  }
*... lots of stocks*
}
```

How can i convert it to this? (to decode later)

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
    "sector": "Technology"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "FB",
    "companyName": "Facebook Inc.",
    "sector": "Technology"
  }
*... lots of stocks*
]
```

It can be not only AAPL or FB, I need optimal answer for lots of "records"

Comment: Don't. The effort to convert the string is much higher than decoding the JSON into structs.

Comment: Please share what you have tried yourself

Comment: Do you know that the format is exactly as above (i.e. each key is on its own line, only ASCII rather than full UTF-8), or is this arbitrary legal JSON? With a known, restricted format, you can perform byte-wise manipulation much faster than full JSON parsing. If the JSON is arbitrary, then it's likely faster to use the built-in JSON parsers unless you're ready to build a custom parser. You can also look for a SAX-style (or streaming) JSON parser, but I haven't seen one for Swift yet.

Comment: If the question is just "how to convert one to other" without performance being the real problem, then that's just "decode to dictionary of structs; map to array of structs, encode array." If that's the question, several people here can definitely write a quick answer for that. It's not clear what you mean by "optimal." Are you having performance problems with this simple approach (if not, then the simple approach is optimal).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem really was no to change the structure but to decode json. I thought that the best way is to bring it to standart form. But I was wrong.I found [an article called "Decode and Flatten JSON with Dynamic Keys Using Decodable"](https://swiftsenpai.com/swift/decode-dynamic-keys-json/). This solved my problem!

```
{
  "S001": {
    "firstName": "Tony",
    "lastName": "Stark"
  },
  "S002": {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Parker"
  },
  "S003": {
    "firstName": "Bruce",
    "lastName": "Wayne"
  }
}

struct DecodedArray: Decodable {

    var array: [Student]
    
    // Define DynamicCodingKeys type needed for creating
    // decoding container from JSONDecoder
    private struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {

        // Use for string-keyed dictionary
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        // Use for integer-keyed dictionary
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            // We are not using this, thus just return nil
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        // 1
        // Create a decoding container using DynamicCodingKeys
        // The container will contain all the JSON first level key
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self)

        var tempArray = [Student]()

        // 2
        // Loop through each key (student ID) in container
        for key in container.allKeys {

            // Decode Student using key & keep decoded Student object in tempArray
            let decodedObject = try container.decode(Student.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            tempArray.append(decodedObject)
        }

        // 3
        // Finish decoding all Student objects. Thus assign tempArray to array.
        array = tempArray
    }
}

struct Student: Decodable {

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    // 1
    // Define student ID
    let studentId: String

    // 2
    // Define coding key for decoding use
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // 3
        // Decode firstName & lastName
        firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.firstName)
        lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.lastName)

        // 4
        // Extract studentId from coding path
        studentId = container.codingPath.first!.stringValue
    }
}
```